# Migrate a List from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

There's a SharePoint List in the 2007 server having some 32 SiteColumns. None of the columns are of type LookUp i.e., there is no dependency of any column over any other Lists. I just need to copy it as it is to 2010 server. Only problem is that it has got items worth more than 10GB size. [*The list has many video attachments*]

Saving the List as template along with its contents is certainly not an option. What I am proposing is to export the entire List to a number of "DAT" files using powershell and then again restoring the same to the 2010 server. This definitely includes manually changing the version of the List from 12 to 14.

Plz advice if there's any better alternative to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating sharepoint with powershell can be troublesome. Try using a tool instead such as metalogix migration:

http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=701a0000002EA67&utm_term=sharepoint%20online%20migration&utm_content=40325388985&gmt=b&gnw=g&gcr=40325388985&gpl=&gkw=sharepoint%20online%20migration&gcm=&gag=General%20SharePoint%20Migration&md=ps

The first 25GBs are free.

Comment: Using metalogix content matrix is a good option. You can write some CSOM script to verify the attachments after migrating the list to SP 2010.